# How can I get the console to log a specific keypoint, i.e. the nose, using facemesh.js (tensorflow)?

Tags: javascript, computer-vision, augmented-reality, tensorflow.js

```
<head>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-core"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/facemesh"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl"></script>
    <script>

    /* running facemesh code */
    async function get_facemesh()
    {

        // load HTML canvas
        var canvas = document.getElementById("facemesh");
        var draw = canvas.getContext("2d");

        // get video stream
        const stream = document.getElementById("movie");

        // load facemesh model
        const model = await facemesh.load(maxFaces=1);

        // process input stream frame by frame
        while(1)
        {
            // fill canvas with black background
            draw.fillStyle = "black";
            draw.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            // detect faces
            const faces = await model.estimateFaces(stream);

            if(faces.length != 0)
            {
                // loop through faces array to capture multiple faces
                var mesh = faces[0].scaledMesh;

                console.log(mesh);

                /* highlight facial landmark points on canvas board */
                draw.fillStyle = "#00FF00";

                for(i=0; i< mesh.length; i++)
                {
                    var [x, y, z] = mesh[i];
                    draw.fillRect(Math.round(x), Math.round(y), 2, 2);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                console.log(`no faces detected..`);
            }

            // loop to process the next frame
            await tf.nextFrame();
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <video width=640 height=480 autoplay id="movie"> </video>
    <canvas width=640 height=480 id="facemesh"> </canvas>

    <br>
    <script>

        // capture live video stream from web camera
        video = document.getElementById("movie");
        if(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia)
        {
                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
                    .then(function (stream) {video.srcObject = stream; });
        }

        // run face-mesh model once the video is ready for processing
        main();

        function main()
        {
            // check if the video is loaded and ready for processing
            if(video.readyState == 4)
            {
                console.log("video is ready for processing..");
                get_facemesh();
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("nope, not loaded yet..");
                setTimeout(main, 1000/30);
            }
        }
       
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is a sample code. This code logs to the console all the facial landmarks, but what I am trying to do is get it to log the landmark only on the nose. How do I do this?

Here is the link to its github: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/facemesh. And here is the link to the facial landmarks: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/master/facemesh/mesh_map.jpg. Here is what I tried: I tried setting a variable called nose equal to getUVCoords(19).
`var nose = getUVCoords(19)` Then I replaced `console.log(mesh)` with `console.log(nose)`.
It did not work. It prevented the whole thing from even running tensorflow. I would appreciate any help  I get on this.

Comment: Can you add a link to your code on glitch or codepen or something I can run in browser and edit? Makes it easier to debug.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems you were overwriting your canvas after you drew the points. Here is code that works for me ovewriting your get_facemesh function:

```
async function get_facemesh()

{

    // load HTML canvas

    var canvas = document.getElementById("facemesh");

    var draw = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // get video stream

    const stream = document.getElementById("movie");

    // load facemesh model

    const model = await facemesh.load(maxFaces=1);

    // process input stream frame by frame
    while(1)

    {
        // detect faces

        const faces = await model.estimateFaces(stream);

        if(faces.length > 0)

        {
            // Reset frame  
          draw.fillStyle = "black";
            draw.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            // loop through faces array to capture multiple faces

            var mesh = faces[0].scaledMesh;

            /* highlight facial landmark points on canvas board */

            draw.fillStyle = "#00FF00";

            for (var i = 0; i < mesh.length; i++) {
              draw.fillRect(mesh[i][0], mesh[i][1], 2, 2);
            }
            

        }

        else

        {

            console.log(`no faces detected..`);

        }

        // loop to process the next frame

        await tf.nextFrame();

    }

}
```

Please note you should almost never  use while(1) instead look into requestAnimationFrame() which is the way to do animation loops. while(1) will for sure give you performance issues as it is an infinite loop and does not wait for browser to do stuff so just dont do that. I will leave it as an exercise for you to clean up your code.

Comment: Thank you so much, the canvas works now!!! Also I figured out the main part of my question, I just needed to access the individual points by using mesh[number of landmark you are trying to access], so if anyone in the future has the same question, this is the answer.